# Animate element, but keep container centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am currently working on a custom lightbox script and need some assistance. I have the animation for the image resizing working great, but I ran into a small problem. The lightbox is shown in the middle of the user's screen, but as soon as I animate the width and height, it doesn't remain in the center of the screen, and just uses the **old** left and top values.

Here's the markup for the lightbox itself:

```
<div id="jqgal_container">
    <div id="jqgal_nav_left" class="jqgal_nav">&lt;</div>
    <div id="jqgal_main">
        <div id="jqgal_main_img"></div>
        <div id="jqgal_footer">
            <div id="jqgal_main_caption"><p></p></div>
            <div id="jqgal_thumbnav_left" class="jqgal_thumbnav">&lt;</div>
            <div id="jqgal_thumbs">
                <div id="jqgal_thumbs_container">
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="jqgal_thumbnav_right" class="jqgal_thumbnav">&gt;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="jqapp_nav_right" class="jqgal_nav">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

The image to be displayed is stored within the `#jqgal_main_img` as an `<img />` element. I animate the width and height of `#jqgal_main_img`, but I also want to keep the whole container (`#jqgal_container`) centered on the screen.

My question is, how can I animate the width of the child element, yet still animate the top and left positions of the container respectively, so it appears to expand and grow from the centre?

The code to animate the width and height of the image container at the moment looks as follows:

```
_resizeToFit : function(img_width, img_height, compFunc)
{
    // Calculate the width and height needed:
    var req_width  = img_width;
    var req_height = img_height;

    this._elements.mainimg.animate({ width: req_width }, {
        duration: 'fast',

        complete: function() {
            $.jqgal._elements.footer.width(req_width);
            $.jqgal._elements.mainimg.animate({ height: req_height }, 'fast', function() {
               if(compFunc != undefined) { compFunc.call(this); }
            });
        },

        step : function() {


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also animate the margin-left and margin-top:

```
  "margin-left" : ($(window).width() - req_width) / 2 
  "margin-top" : ($(window).height() - req_height) / 2
```

If the elements CSS position is 'absolute', change margin-top / margin-left to top and left.

EDIT:

At the end of the whole 'animate' string, add

```
.parent().animate({
          "margin-left" : )($(window).width() - req_width) / 2) + this._elements.mainimg.parent().scrollLeft(),
  "margin-top" : (($(window).height() - req_height) / 2 ) + this._elements.mainimg.parent().scrollTop()
}}
```

Or in the callback function:

```
$(this).parent().animate({...});
```

For ease, it might be best to set variables holding the elements too...

```
$this = this._elements.mainimg;
$parent = $this.parent();
```

Then the parent animate() data would look like this:

```
         "margin-left" : )($(window).width() - req_width) / 2) + $parent.scrollLeft(),
  "margin-top" : (($(window).height() - req_height) / 2 ) + $parent.scrollTop()
}}
```

Which is a little easier to read!

Comment: That is animating the margins of `mainimg`. I want / need to animate the margins of the parent element (`#jqgal_container`)...

Comment: Edited with more info on .parent()

Comment: Thanks! Unless I'm mistaken though, those calculations won't take into consideration the user's scrolled position on the page (i.e. scrollTop)?

Comment: No, they won't, but it's easy enough to add the stuff that gets the scroll position to it, just add the number to the amount. Editing again!

Comment: Edited! I forget some people allow scrolling on their sites! I made a custom scroll bar plugin for jQuery and now always make my <body> tag's CSS overflow:hidden!

Answer (score -1):

i think you should Animate too the margin's and left distance.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do, but I need to animate the left and top positions of the **container** at the same ratio as the main image container is resized.